# passing and displaying json data between activities not working?

Tags: java, android, json

i have a listview of json data and when i click on the specific , i have tried to display the rest of the json data in a new activity by using the intent method. however, this is not working. can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong please?

my code:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `searchResults` variable, is an **ArrayList** of Strings not a **String**.

So you need to use `putStringArrayListExtra()` and `getStringArrayListExtra()` instead.

eg:

In your first activity:

```
newActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("title", searchResults);
```

And in your receiving activity:

```
 ArrayList<String> searchResults = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("title");
```

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra();
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ArrayList<String> searchResults =   getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("title");
is this correct in my receiving activity?

Comment: You don't need this line: `Bundle extras = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra();` . For the rest it's OK.

Comment: i deleted the line but it's still not displaying in the MoviePage. thank you for all the help you have provided so far.

Comment: You have to get the desired string from the ArrayList and set it to your text ( *tv.setText(searchResults.get(desiredIndex);* )

Comment: stupid question but what would the desiredIndex be please. i'm really bad at rereading my code all the names confuse me.

Comment: I don't know which string you want, it depends on your needs.

Comment: title, year, plot, genre etc

Comment: omg it displays the data now but only the title and year of the first item in the listview. thank you so much for correcting my mistake - i have really progressed im so happy lol

Comment: thank you so so so much mr rami i wish you all the happiness in the world!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
```

to

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MovieDetails.class);
```

You are targeting the wrong `Activity`.

### EDIT:

the `searchResults` variable contains an **int**, so you have to use `getInt()` instead of `getString()`.

Comment: changed it but it's still not showing. thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Put some logging information in . i.e. check searchResults actually contains a string of text before startActvity

Comment: no, it doesn't crash but it doesn't display anything at all in the textview i assigned it to.

Comment: in the debugging thing it says searchResults: size = 10

Comment: check the searchResults is empty or not @pinktoky89

Comment: i have updated my code. the data i'm trying to pass consists of strings, i have no idea where size = 10 came from